# Splitting a Byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte

Is it possible to get specific bytes from a byte array in java?

I have a byte array:

```
byte[] abc = new byte[512];
```

and i want to have 3 different byte arrays from this array.

1. byte 0-127
2. byte 128-255
3. byte256-511.

I tried `abc.read(byte[], offset,length)` but it works only if I give offset as 0, for any other value it throws an `IndexOutOfbounds` exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The offset is at the destination array, not the source one.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays.copyOfRange()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) for that.

Comment: Whoa. Didn't know about that.

Comment: @Jonathan Feinberg: It's new in Java 6.

Comment: @Tara note that the end range should not be same as start range. ie if you are extracting from 0,127 then it should be Arrays.copyOfRange(record,0,128);

Answer (score 15):

`Arrays.copyOfRange()` is introduced in Java 1.6. If you have an older version it is internally using [`System.arraycopy(...)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29). Here's how it is implemented:

```
public static <U> U[] copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to) {
    Class<? extends U[]> newType = (Class<? extends U[]>) original.getClass();
    int newLength = to - from;
    if (newLength < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
    }
    U[] copy = ((Object) newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (U[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (U[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: -1 this is not the same as the standard version. It is not type-safe (you can pass it an `Integer[]` and assign the result to a `String[]` variable.) `Arrays.copyOfRange(T[], int, int)` returns `T[]`. You may be mixing it up with the other version that takes a `Class` argument.

Comment: @finnw: the other method is just overloaded. I merged them but forgot to remove the 2nd type parameter. Now it's fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use byte buffers as views on top of the original array as well.

Comment: `ByteBuffer skip4Bytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 4, bytes.length - 4);`