# split a byte array...?

Tags: java, split, arrays

Every time i come across the value "-15" i want to put it in a new byte array... how would i do this? I think i'm just tired and getting way to confused and worked up... please help... code is as follows:

```
    fileContent = "S107184CB78120EA52S107184CB78120EA57"; 
    int len = fileContent.length(); 
    byte[] data = new byte[len/2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) 
    {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(fileContent.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(fileContent.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
```

this will give me the following: [-15, 7, 24, 76, -73, -127, 32, -22, 82, -15, 7, 24, 76, -73, -127, 32, -22, 87]

what i want from here is to have every element from -15 up until the next -15 (but not including it) in a separate byte array. i want to do that every time i come across another -15.. how would i do this?

Comment: Iterate over the array, and every time you see a -15, create a new array and following elements to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Splitting a Byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253912/splitting-a-byte-array)

Comment: (Not an exact duplicate, but if the OP can't adapt one of those answers, he's got much bigger problems ...)

Comment: @StephenC you mean SHE.. and i've just looked at it now.... who said i wouldn't accept an answer?!

Comment: @StephenC it's not a duplicate either...

Comment: @BlueMonster - 1) if you hide your gender behind an alias, you've got no right to object if someone guesses wrong.  2) my point was that you didn't need to ask this question in the first place.  A similar question has been answered already, and the answers are BETTER than the one that you accepted.

Comment: @BlueMonster - *"it's not a duplicate either... "* I know that!  Why do think I commented *"(Not an exact duplicate, but ... "*???

Comment: @StephenC oh i see... BlueMonsters can only be males huh... lol interesting.. "better" dependent on what you need accomplished. For my purposes, this works perfectly...

Comment: @BlueMonster - my assumptions about imaginary constructs are beside the point.  If you don't want people to guess your gender wrong, don't hide it.  After all, the purpose of hiding your gender is (I presume) that you think it shouldn't be relevant.  And if it is irrelevant, why did you even bring up the topic?  You can't have it both ways ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `-15`'s occur randomly, you need a dynamic array, which in java is a `List`.
Once you've collected up all your elements, you can convert the List to an array easily enough.

It would look something like this:

```
String fileContent = "S107184CB78120EA52S107184CB78120EA57";
int len = fileContent.length();
List<Byte[]> arrays = new ArrayList<Byte[]>();
List<Byte> data = new ArrayList<Byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
    byte b = (byte) ((Character.digit(fileContent.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(fileContent.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    if (b == -15) {
        arrays.add(data.toArray(new Byte[data.size()]));
        data.clear();
    }
    data.add(b);
}
arrays.add(data.toArray(new Byte[data.size()]));
```

Note that this creates a `List<Byte[]>`, not a `List<byte[]>`. I chose this because I could use the `.toArray()` method of `List`.  If you want a `List<byte[]>`, you'll need to manually literate over `data` in the if block.

Comment: Sorry, but you can do this a lot more simply and efficiently using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` - see link to earlier question.  Of course, this is irrelevant to the OP if she just wants something she can copy and paste.  But there are other people out there who might care about this.

Comment: @StephenC If I could give you rep for a comment I would. Good tip!